# Using Mass and Density of a Sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

**Question**: A sphere of radius $R$ has total mass $M$ and density function given by $ρ = kr$, where $r$ is the distance a point lies from the centre of the sphere. Give an expression for the constant $k$ in terms of $M$ and $R$.

**My Attempt**: $ρ$ is defined as density, meaning $ρ=\frac{M}{Volume}$. Volume of a sphere $= \frac{4}{3}\pi R^3$. Therefore, $ρ=\frac{M}{\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3}=\frac{3M}{4\pi R^3}$. Substituting in $ρ = kr$, I am left with $$kr=\frac{3M}{4\pi R^3}$$ and therefore need to find an expression for $r$ in terms of $k$, $M$ and/or $R$, but am unsure how to continue from here.

Please help!

Comment: density = mass/volume is only true if density is a constant, which it is not. You are told it is a function.

Comment: The sphere in the question is solid, but think of it as being made up of many hollow concentric spherical shells, each shell being $ \delta r$ thick.  Each shell has uniform density and for the shell with radius $ r, 0 \leq r \leq R $ the mass is $ \rho(r) \cdot 4\pi r^2 \delta r $.  Use calculus to calculate the total mass in terms of $ \rho$ and equate to $ M $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a shell of infinitesimal thickness $dr$ at a distance $r$ from the centre. The mass of this shell would be
$$dM = 4\pi r^2dr \times \rho(r) = 4 \pi r^2 kr dr$$
Then integrate both sides to find the mass as a function of $k$
$$M = \int_0^R 4 \pi r^2 \cdot kr dr = 4\pi k \frac{R^4}{4}$$
Therefore, the value of k is
$$\boxed{k = \frac{M}{\pi R^4}}$$

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how you got that integral?

Comment: I'll edit to add some verbosity.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider a spherical shell with radius $r$ and thickness $dr$, then

[image]

Now, to find the mass of this spherical shell

\begin{align}
\text{Volume of spherical shell } &= \text{Surface area} \times \text{Thickness} \\
&= 4\pi r^{2} \cdot dr
\end{align}

Since $\rho = kr$,

\begin{align}
\text{Mass } &= \text{Volume} \times \text{Density} \\
&= 4 \pi k r^{3}dr
\end{align}

Now, to find the mass of the sphere, we integrate the above from $r=0$ to $r=R$

\begin{align}
M &= \int_{0}^{R} 4 \pi k r^{3} dr \\
&= 4 \pi k \int_{0}^{R} r^{3} dr \\
&= 4 \pi k \left[\frac{r^4}{4} \right]_{0}^{R} \\
&= \pi k R^{4}
\end{align}

Thus, an expression for the constant $k$ in terms of $M$ and $R$ is

$$k = \frac{M}{\pi R^{4}}$$